# Yii2 Loading and saving ActiveForm

Tags: yii2, active-form

Model:

```
class Team extends ActiveRecord {
    public function rules() {
        return [
            [['code', 'name'], 'required'],
        ];
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
class TeamController extends ActiveController {
    public $modelClass = 'frontend\models\Team';
    protected function verbs(){
        return [
            'create' => ['POST'],
        ];
    }
}
```

View:

```
<?php Pjax::begin(['id' => 'new_team']) ?>
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['action' => 'team/create'], 'options' => ['data-pjax' => true ]]); ?>
    <?= $form->field($model, 'code')->textInput() ?>
    <?= $form->field($model, 'name')->textInput() ?>
    <div class="form-group">
        <?= Html::submitButton(Yii::t('app', 'Create'), ['class' => 'btn btn-success']) ?>
    </div>
<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
<?php Pjax::end(); ?>
```

Form's fields will have Team[code] and Team[name] as name attribute values. I would like them to be name="code" and name="name" instead. At the moment when I submit the form I get:

```
[{"field":"code",
  "message":"Code cannot be blank."},
 {"field":"name",
  "message":"Name cannot be blank."}]
```

How can I change name attribute's value?

Comment: so you want that the names of the inputs should not be `Team[code]` but it should be `code` but why you want to do that don't you want to save them into the databases? what do you actually want to accomplish maybe i could help you in a better way

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam Yes, that is correct and I do want to save them to database. I'm already updating this table in another place where it works when I use just "code" and just "name". But I'm not creating the form there with `ActiveForm`. Thanks for any help you can offer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The current format of the `name` attribute `Team[code]` is because `YiiActiveForm` uses the Model Information to generate the input names in the format `ModelName[FieldName]` this helps to reduce the effort to manually assigning the `post` fields to the model fields before saving and if you do not want the form field names to follow `ActiveForm` format you need to use [`yii\helpers\Html`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-helper-html.html) helper to create the form and fields but be careful as you will need to map the field to hte model manually now so what you have to do is change your form declaration from

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['action' => 'team/create'], 'options' => ['data-pjax' => true ]]); ?>
    <?= $form->field($model, 'code')->textInput() ?>
    <?= $form->field($model, 'name')->textInput() ?>
    <div class="form-group">
        <?= Html::submitButton(Yii::t('app', 'Create'), ['class' => 'btn btn-success']) ?>
    </div>
<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

To

```
<?= yii\helpers\Html::beginForm(['team/create', 'id' => 'team-form'], 'post', ['data-pjax' => true]) ?>
     <?= yii\helpers\Html::activeInput('text',$model, 'code')?>
     <?= yii\helpers\Html::activeInput('text',$model, 'name')?>
    <div class="form-group">
        <?= Html::submitButton(Yii::t('app', 'Create'), ['class' => 'btn btn-success']) ?>
    </div>
<?= Html::endForm() ?>
```

**EDIT**

As per discussion the OP had to revert back to `ActiveForm` and was trying to save record but having a problem so I thought I might add this info in the answer maybe it would help out someone.

in order to use `ActiveForm` when you submit your form to any `controller/action` you need to look there that if you are properly loading the `model` with the `post` array using

```
$model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())
```

and then call `$model->save()` or `$model->validate()`, apart from this try `print_r($model->attributes)` right after you call `$model->load()` to check if the values are properly loaded into the `model`.

Comment: So I chose the wrong tool for my task. Would I have to change my model or controller in order to keep using `ActiveForm`? You say `ModelName[FieldName]` helps to reduce the effort, but at the moment I get a response that `code` and `name` don't have value, which implies that `ModelName[FieldName]` is not the format that my controller or model expects. Do I have to change my controller or model in order to use the `ModelName[FieldName]` format?

Comment: in order to use active form when you submit you form to any controller action you need to look there that if you are properly loading the model with the post array using `$model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())` and then call `$model->save()` or `$model->validate()`, apart from this try `print_r($model->attributes)` right after you call `$model->load()` to check if the values are properly loaded into the model @Harry